# Custom NSFormatter causes build error "Class Unavailable: Custom Formatter with XCode versions prior to 4.1"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.2

I'm using XCode 4.2.1. I created a custom `NSFormatter` which I added in IB to a text field. The formatter works fine, but building generates a `Class Unavailable: Custom Formatter with XCode versions prior to 4.1` - error. I can even run the application after the build.

Any ideas what this means and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this part of the property sheet for your xib:

[image]

Probably you need to change the selection for **Development** either to **Xcode 4.1** or **Default Version (Xcode 4.1)**.